# Having trouble using QThread to setup graphics apart from main ui thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface

I know there are many things that can go awry with multi-threading, and it seems to be happening to me here.

I'm a little baffled though because I'm using the signals and slots which are supposedly thread safe, yet still getting errors similar to what I see other people on the web getting who aren't using signals and slots.

Here's my situation:

1. From my main ui thread, I create a new thread and move an object to it
2. The second thread starts, and the object processes some data.
3. When the processing is done, the object emits a `setScene` signal I have created back to the ui thread, landing in a slot.
4. The slot does: `QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(sceneIncoming);`
5. Then it does: `ui->graphicsView.setScene(scene);

This still tells me I can't create a child from a parent in another thread.  I don't understand how to update a graphicsView in the main thread with the scene data from the 2nd thread, despite me using signals and slots.

**Edit: Added code snippets**

mainwindow.cpp constructor

```
...
...
QThread *thread = new QThread();
GraphicsWorker *worker = new GraphicsWorker();
this->worker = worker;


this->worker->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();

QObject::connect(this, &MainWindow::beginGraphicsWorker, this->worker, &GraphicsWorker::run);
QObject::connect(worker, &GraphicsWorker::setScene, this, &MainWindow::setScene);
...
....
```

GraphicsWorker.cpp run()

```
...processing
...processing
...processing
painter->fillPath(*path, Qt::blue);

scene->addPath(*path);



emit setScene(scene);
```

mainwindow.cpp setScene slot

```
void MainWindow::setScene(QGraphicsScene *sceneIncoming)
{
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(sceneIncoming);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
}
```

The above snippets are posted in order of operation.  So again, I want to hand off some processing involving a QPainterPath and QGraphicsScene that's intensive and blocks the GUI, then pass the data back to the main thread once the processing is done, and let the main thread update the graphicsView widget with the scene data from the processing thread.  I figured copying the `sceneIncoming` into a new object would let the new object be owned in the main thread, yet have the data of the scene from the processing thread, yet it doesn't appear to work that easily.

**Perhaps instead of `emit setScene(scene)`, I need scene.moveToThread(mainThread)??** In that case I guess I need to pass a reference to the main thread into the graphics worker.

**EDIT 2: SOLVED**
Actually I needed both of these lines of code:

```
scene.moveToThread(this->mainThread);
emit setScene(scene);
```

I also added an overloaded constructor passing in the main thread reference.

Everything works smoothly now.  I am still open to suggestions on how to better do this or if this is still the wrong way. Let me know!

Comment: There are so many possible problems here, but if you add a code example, rather than a description, we'd be able to assist you much quicker. Also note that you cannot do anything UI related on any other thread than the main one.

Comment: i am not shure, but the `QObject::connect()` will want `char*`s from the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macro

Comment: @Zaiborg What? I wasn't having trouble with the signal/slot connecting at all.  That part is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to you requesting a better way of doing this, I would suggest you leave the QPainter object in the main thread. Then, have the second thread process data and emit signals to the main thread to pass the data that it has processed, where the data is then added to the QPainter object on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
scene->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".